# Why can't I interact with SSH using subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I'm trying to interact with SSH using Python's `subprocess` library. Here's my current code:

```
import subprocess
import time
proc = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-tt", "user@host"],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(10)
proc.stdin.write(b"ls\n")
while True:
    next_line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if next_line != '':
        print(next_line.decode("utf-8"), end='')
    else:
        time.sleep(.01)
```

When I run it, I get the usual SSH security banner, but nothing else. I log in via public key and have already added the host to my known_hosts list, so I would imagine authentication shouldn't be an issue. By changing `ls` to a command to write text to a file, I have confirmed that no commands are "going through." What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using ssh manually on the command line ? Just to make sure that ssh itself works properly.

Comment: @AedvaldTseh Yes, SSH is working properly. I wasn't flushing the stream - rookie mistake :(. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to call `proc.stdin.flush()`.  More generally, you should use [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) instead, which is a Python library for SSH directly, rather than using Popen for this.

Comment: God bless you, that did it. My reasons for not using Paramiko are a story of great woe and misery, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Pythonish: Great, glad you got it sorted.  Let me guess: Your employer somehow prevents you from installing new libraries?

Comment: Yeah, they discourage it pretty strongly. Plus the library isn't exactly lightweight, plus compiling the crypto dependencies is a pain, etc, etc.